# New column specifying if time interval falls into a particular grouping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, time

I have Zoom data of when people checked in and checked out, and I would like to match those time intervals by the session that was going on and create a new column with a list of sessions the participant attended.

If the time spent in a session is less than 10 minutes, I don't want to include it.

Example:

Sessions

| Session | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | 8:00-8:30 |
| Oranges | 8:30-9:00 |
| Pineapples | 9:00-9:30 |

Participants

| Participant | Join Time | Leave Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 8:03 | 8:40 |
| 001 | 9:04 | 9:31 |
| 002 | 8:45 | 9:00 |
| 003 | 8:00 | 8:30 |
| 003 | 8:55 | 9:00 |
| 003 | 9:02 | 9:25 |

Desired output:

| participant | Engaged Sessions |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Apples,Oranges,Pineapples |
| 002 | Oranges |
| 003 | Apples, Pineapples |

Would anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Thank you kindly for the help

Answer (score 0):

Before presenting a possible solution allow me to point out some points that would be more favorable to handle differently than described in the problem statement.

- Time and sessions: Where possible use session with dates.
- Use time aware timestamps. Especially with sessions over different time zones it becomes really messy when only using hours and minutes. Before starting to evaluate, bring all timestamps to the same time zone.
- String concatenations are rarely used and make further processing difficult. If the problem really requires this make sure it is one of the final steps and you don't need to manipulate further.

Now to the solution proposed.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
         Participant    Join Time    Leave Time    
 0   001      8:03      8:40     
 1   001      9:04      9:31
 2   002      8:45      9:00      
 3   003      8:00      8:30
 4   003      8:55      9:00       
 5   003      9:02      9:25   
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python", dtype=object)
df['Join Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Join Time']+':00')    # make it a timedelta
df['Leave Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Leave Time']+':00')  # make it a timedelta
df['Time spent'] = df['Leave Time']-df['Join Time']    # for side condition

sess_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
         Session    Time    
 0   Apples      8:00-8:30     
 1   Oranges      8:30-9:00
 2   Pineapples      9:00-9:30   
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python", dtype=object)
sess_df['Start'] = sess_df.Time.str.split(pat="-",expand=True)[0]
sess_df['Start'] = pd.to_timedelta(sess_df['Start']+':00')
sess_df['End'] = sess_df.Time.str.split(pat="-",expand=True)[1]
sess_df['End'] = pd.to_timedelta(sess_df['End']+':00')
```

Expand the `df` with the sessions from the `sess_df`

```
df = df.reindex(columns=list(df.columns) + list(sess_df.Session.unique()),fill_value=False)
```

Logic for participation:

```
for sess in list(sess_df.Session.unique()):
    df.loc[df[(df['Time spent'].dt.total_seconds()>(10 * 60)) &  # at least 10 min in session?
      (((df['Join Time'].dt.total_seconds() >= list(sess_df[sess_df.Session==sess].Start)[0].total_seconds()) &
      (df['Join Time'].dt.total_seconds() <= list(sess_df[sess_df.Session==sess].End)[0].total_seconds()))|
      ((df['Leave Time'].dt.total_seconds() > list(sess_df[sess_df.Session==sess].Start)[0].total_seconds()+0.1) &
      (df['Leave Time'].dt.total_seconds() <= list(sess_df[sess_df.Session==sess].End)[0].total_seconds()+0.1)))
      ].index, sess] =True
```

**Output processing**

```
df = df[df[list(sess_df.Session.unique())].any(1)].groupby('Participant').sum()
df = df.T
participant = []
sess_string = []
for p in list(df.columns):
    participant.append(p)
    tmp = ''
    for sess in list(df[df[p]==True].index):
        if tmp == '':
            tmp = sess
        else:
            tmp = tmp +','+ sess
    sess_string.append(tmp)

desired_output=pd.DataFrame(data={'participant':participant, 'Engaged Sessions':sess_string}).set_index('participant')
```

**Comments**

Note that before the output processing you have a `df` with the sessions and a boolean map whether or not a participant was in the session.

Also to the points in the introduction. Here timedeltas are used wo be able to work with HH:MM. There is a great example why you should used timestamps with dates rather than timedeltas. In the logic for the session participation on the leave Time `+0.1` are added. Taking the Orange session.

```
list(sess_df[sess_df.Session=='Oranges'].Start)[0].total_seconds()
```

this returns `30600.0` what is 08:30

```
df['Leave Time'].dt.total_seconds()>list(sess_df[sess_df.Session=='Oranges'].Start)[0].total_seconds()
```

This would return to you that all `Leave Time` are greater than 08:30 what is not correct. One is exactly 08:30. Numerically `30600.0 > 30600.0` would return `False`. This being said be carefull when not using full timestamps and calculating with time in general.